# Auto suggestions missing for built in locators like goto, click, fill in Playwright Javascript

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, pom, playwright

I am doing playwright java script automation using POM cucumber BDD framework.
I initiated page object in Hooks file.

If I want to access that page object in another methods in the same file it is not giving me auto suggested locators like (goto, click, fill, getByLabel).

Like below I have pasted my code, when I wanted to use `this.page` in `AfterStep` hook it is not giving me auto suggestions for `screenshot`.

And when I import this file into step file there also not getting auto suggestions for built in locators

```
const { Before, After, AfterStep, Status, result} = require('@cucumber/cucumber')
const playwright = require('playwright')
const { chromium } = playwright
const {PageObjectFactory} = require('../Pages/PageObjectFactory')
let status = result;
let page ;

Before(async function(){
    const browser = await chromium.launch({headless:false})
    this.browser = browser
    const context = await browser.newContext()
    this.context = context
    page = await context.newPage()
    this.page = page
})

AfterStep(async function ({ result }) {
    if (result.status === Status.FAILED) {
        await this.page.screenshot({ path: Date.now()+'screenshot1.png' });
    }
});
```